# How to control datatable primefaces columns to look like advent calendar?

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I'm designing a web application advent calendar where the admin set the information of the gifts for each day. I spent so much time trying to make it look like a calendar but no lock. I want it to look like advent calender, for example: 
header will be something like this:

MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN

1   2      3     4     5     6     7

8   9   10  11  12  13  14

and so on ...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a panelgrid with clickable cells? For example with the use of commandlink inside each cell.